# Mysterious gap in footer

Tags: html, css

Changing the footer around on a site and having a hard time trying to troubleshoot why I am getting a gap in the footer of the site. Looking to have the .footer_container with a white background. I have an .aux class with some additional copyright and contact info that is kept in the footer container but is not carrying the white background color from the footer container?? Am I missing something? Possibly something staring right at me that I simply overlooked?
Any help would be appreciated.

Site is located [here][1]

css

```
#footer_container {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 216px;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
}

.container_16 {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 960px;
}

.container_16 .grid_4 {
    width: 220px;
}

#footer_container footer nav li {
    margin: 0 5px
}

#footer_container footer nav li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 -5px;
    padding: 2px 5px;
    color: #222222
}

#footer_container footer a:hover {
    background-color: #fbfed9;
    color: #222222
}

#footer_container footer #footer_nav_container {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-image: ;
}

#footer_container footer #footer_teaser {
    position: relative;
    height: 141px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
    text-indent: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#footer_container footer nav li {
    margin: 0 5px;
}

#footer_container footer .aux {
    clear: both;
    padding: 7px 5px;
    margin: 10px 10px 24px;
    border-top: 1px dotted #9d9d9d;
    color: #222222;
    font-family: "Apercu Regular", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 9px;
    line-height: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#footer_container footer .aux a {
    margin: 0 -3px;
    padding: 1px 3px;
}

#footer_container footer .aux div {
    float: left;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#footer_container footer .aux .contact {
    float: right
}

#footer_container footer .aux .contact div {
    margin-left: 16px
}

#footer_container footer .aux .contact .cta {
    font-family: "Apercu Bold", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes are needed.

First disable `padding-bottom: 40px` of `.page` class.

```
.page {
  display: block;
  /* padding-bottom: 40px; */
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 10px; }
```

And disable forced `height: 216px` of `#footer_container' div.

```
#footer_container {
    position: relative;
    clear: both;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    /* height: 316px; */
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<footer>` doesn't have a background on it. The `#footer_nav_container` has a white background on it, but the `.aux` div is a child of `<footer>`, sitting below `#footer_nav_container`, so it also does not have a background being applied to it. I believe that applying a white background to footer with a simple

```
footer{
background-color:#FFF
}
```

will bridge the gap

Comment: The `#F7F7F7` in the #footer_teaser is a placeholder for now. I was actually referring to the gap in the .aux div with the copyright info and contact number. I'll go ahead and revise the question to clarify a bit more. Thank you for the help so far.